# Client cannot see the server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp

Hi guys i am using windows server 2008, i set up a domain, and several clients joined. the server can see the client and the client pc which using windows xp cannot see the server.

from the server side, it is connected as shown below:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.118 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.118: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.118: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.118: bytes=32 time=85ms TTL=128
```

and the client computer can be seen at the server IP : `192.168.1.111`, but from the client side i can't see the server.

and the the connection from server to the PC using ping shows ok:

and from pc to server connection:

How can i access the server from the client pc, since it is already joined the domain?

Comment: Have you disabled the firewall on the server?

Comment: @EEAA, yeah just disabled. still the same. if the client already joined the domain, shouldn't be the server shown on my networks? i tried to connect using ` \\server\ `, it say it cannot find the server.

Comment: What kind of network nastiness do you have going on where it's taking 30-80ms to ping between client and server? Is there some VPN/WAN involved or is this all on the same L2 LAN?

Comment: @EEAA, it is wifi connection

Comment: Is "server" a domain controller?
From XP client run & post here:
"ipconfig /all"
"nbtstat -A 192.168.1.118"
Confirm all DNS IP on all NICs are set to IP of DC(s), no external DNS.
There s/b errors in the event log about authentication, etc if there is no connectivity to the DC,  post any relevant errors.

Comment: @EdFries, yes it is domain controller. the ipconfig/all gives: `  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1C-BF-65-1B-BC
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.118
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.192.1.111
                                            8.8.8.8 ` the netstat command i will post below.

Comment: netstat: `Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:http   free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENING
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:epmap  free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENING
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:microsoft-ds  free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENI
NG
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:3306   free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENING
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:3389   free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENING
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:5555   free2mov-b25fb8.Sensmaster.net:0  LISTENING
  
 ` i will continue below.

Comment: continued: ` TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:1100   ni-in-f17.1e100.net:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    free2mov-b25fb8:1155   ni-in-f138.1e100.net:https  ESTABLISHED
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:microsoft-ds  *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:isakmp  *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:4500   *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:ntp    *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:1900   *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:ntp    *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:netbios-ns  *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:netbios-dgm  *:*
  UDP    free2mov-b25fb8:1900   *:*`  from the event logs there are no errors, just few warnings.

Answer (score 0):

From your Ipconfig info, remove the 8.8.8.8 DNS entry from the DCHP scope, restart DHCP service and renew the lease on the client.   Fixed?

Use only internal servers for DNS in an AD domain.  If/when a PC switches to a secondary DNS server it won't change back to primary until the next restart so AD name resolution will fail in the meantime.

If that doesn't resolve it then:
You posted netstat when I asked for nbtstat -A 192.168.1.118. (Edit your question and post the info there, much easier to read than in the comments.) 
Post exact error messages, we will need more specific info than "cannot be seen".
Disable the wireless & only connect via LAN, does it work correctly?